# Contingency table - how to obtain the row total

Tags: r

I using the mtcars data set to produce a 2x2 table of vs var (binary 0/1 variables) and cyl var (3 categories). I currently have  a contingency table where the cells sum to 100% in the entire table. I am trying to obtain the row total percent that is the percent of observations taking a value of 0 or 1, given a cyl var category

```
  summary(mtcars)
  typeof(mtcars$cyl)
  table(mtcars$cyl)
  contingency_table <- prop.table(table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$cyl))

  view(contingency_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
with(mtcars, cbind(prop.table(table(vs, cyl)), prop.table(table(vs))))
        4       6      8       
0 0.03125 0.09375 0.4375 0.5625
1 0.31250 0.12500 0.0000 0.4375
```

Or if you already have `contingency_table`:

```r
cbind(contingency_table, rowSums(contingency_table))
```

---

If you want marginal percentages, specify the `margin` argument (1 for rows, 2 for columns):

```r
prop.table(table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$cyl), margin = 2)
             4          6          8
  0 0.09090909 0.42857143 1.00000000
  1 0.90909091 0.57142857 0.00000000
```